# How to index MySQL from ElasticSearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

Im trying to add some full text searching to my LAMP web application. Ive come across ElasticSearch and I like what it has to offer. I have read the guides and understand how to index a single item by using curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/.

But how can I index an entire MySQL database? 
I cannot seem to find anywhere on the web that explains how to do this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to mirror the parts you want searched in elastic search.. you just don't tell elastic search to index a mysql database.

Basically whatever gets put/changed/deleted in mysql also has to do the same in elastic search. You don't have to put all the info just what you want to search on and a way to link it to the mysql info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a river to pull data from your MySQL database.

[GitHub: elasticsearch-river-jdbc](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc)

[Installation instructions](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Quickstart)

But I've seen more recommendations to have your app push the data using bulk operations.

[StackOverflow: How to index JSON web services into elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202759/how-to-index-json-web-services-into-elasticsearch)